# Create a reactive variable depending on active Tab on R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dynamic-variables, shinydashboardplus

I have this simple app and I would like to be able to "catch" the active tab.
For example, if I'm on "tab1", my selectInput at the top would be c("a","b","c") but it would change if I am on the other tab
I want to create a variable `active_tab` that would be dynamic but I have no idea how to do it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    title="Shiny Dashboard",
    header = shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(
      title = "Example",
      leftUi = tagList(
        uiOutput("reactive_ui")
      )),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("tab1",tabName = "tab1"),
        menuItem("tab2",tabName = "tab2")
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem("tab1"),
        tabItem("tab2")
      )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$reactive_ui =renderUI({
      if (active_tab == "tab1") choice = c("a","b","c","d") 
      if (active_tab == "tab2") choice = c("e","f","g")
      
      selectInput("select", NULL,choices = choice )
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sidebarMenu` contains an `id` parameter that can be used to retrieve the name of the active tab on the server side.

If it is just the `selectInput` you want to update on the tab change, then have a look at `updateSelectInput` so that you can update the choices without having to re-render the input every time the tab changes. It also means the input is defined once the application opens.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    title = "Shiny Dashboard",
    header = shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(
      title = "Example",
      leftUi = tagList(
        selectInput("select", NULL, choices = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
      )
    ),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "tab",
        menuItem("tab1", tabName = "tab1"),
        menuItem("tab2", tabName = "tab2")
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem("tab1"),
        tabItem("tab2")
      )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$tab, {
      if (input$tab == "tab1") {
        choices <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
      } else if (input$tab == "tab2") {
        choices <- c("e", "f", "g")
      }
      updateSelectInput(session, "select", choices = choices)
    })
  }
)
```